# Flatten an array

Tags: list-manipulation

I have obtained an array of results as follows

```
{{{w -> 0.25}}, {{w -> 0.05}}, {{w -> 0.190065}, {w -> 
    0.0182686}}, {{w -> 0.0404842}, {w -> 0.0086731}}, {{w -> 
    0.156634}, {w -> 0.015429}, {w -> 0.00478921}}, {{w -> 
    0.0344873}, {w -> 0.00753932}, {w -> 0.00292085}}, {{w -> 
    0.134788}, {w -> 0.0134812}, {w -> 0.00424987}, {w -> 
    0.00191167}}, {{w -> 0.0302949}, {w -> 0.00671401}, {w -> 
    0.0026321}, {w -> 0.00131905}}, {{w -> 0.119177}, {w -> 
    0.012046}, {w -> 0.00383985}, {w -> 0.0017433}, {w -> 
    0.000948279}}}
```

I want to extract numbers only as an ordered list namely

```
{0.25, 0.05, 0.190065,0.0182686, ...}
```

when I use `Flatten` command I get first number of each inner list, How can extract all numbers as sorted list?

Comment: `Values@list // Flatten`  or `Flatten@list // Values` or `Values@Flatten@list` or `Flatten@Values@list`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
a = {{{w -> 0.25}}, {{w -> 0.05}}, {{w -> 0.190065}, {w -> 
    0.0182686}}, {{w -> 0.0404842}, {w -> 0.0086731}}, {{w -> 
    0.156634}, {w -> 0.015429}, {w -> 0.00478921}}, {{w -> 
    0.0344873}, {w -> 0.00753932}, {w -> 0.00292085}}, {{w -> 
    0.134788}, {w -> 0.0134812}, {w -> 0.00424987}, {w -> 
    0.00191167}}, {{w -> 0.0302949}, {w -> 0.00671401}, {w -> 
    0.0026321}, {w -> 0.00131905}}, {{w -> 0.119177}, {w -> 
    0.012046}, {w -> 0.00383985}, {w -> 0.0017433}, {w -> 
    0.000948279}}}

w /. a // Flatten
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Flatten[lst][[All, -1]]
```

> {0.25, 0.05, 0.190065, 0.0182686, 0.0404842, 0.0086731, 0.156634, 
>   0.015429, 0.00478921, 0.0344873, 0.00753932, 0.00292085, 0.134788, 
>   0.0134812, 0.00424987, 0.00191167, 0.0302949, 0.00671401, 0.0026321, 
>   0.00131905, 0.119177, 0.012046, 0.00383985, 0.0017433, 0.000948279}

Also

```
Values @ Flatten @ lst
```

> same result

```
Flatten @ Values @ lst
```

> same result

```
Cases[lst, _Real, All]
```

> same result

Answer (score 6):

For the general case where you only want rules with the left-hand-side 'w':

```
Cases[{{{w->0.25}},{{w->0.05}},{{w->0.190065},{w->0.0182686}},{{w->0.0404842},{w->0.0086731}},{{w->0.156634},{w->0.015429},{w->0.00478921}},{{w->0.0344873},{w->0.00753932},{w->0.00292085}},{{w->0.134788},{w->0.0134812},{w->0.00424987},{w->0.00191167}},{{w->0.0302949},{w->0.00671401},{w->0.0026321},{w->0.00131905}},{{w->0.119177},{w->0.012046},{w->0.00383985},{w->0.0017433},{w->0.000948279}}},
 (w->x_):>x,
 \[Infinity]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another few ways centered around `Level`.

```
data = {{{w -> 0.25}}, {{w -> 0.05}}, {{w -> 0.190065}, {w -> 
 0.0182686}}, {{w -> 0.0404842}, {w -> 0.0086731}}, {{w -> 
 0.156634}, {w -> 0.015429}, {w -> 0.00478921}}, {{w -> 
 0.0344873}, {w -> 0.00753932}, {w -> 0.00292085}}, {{w -> 
 0.134788}, {w -> 0.0134812}, {w -> 0.00424987}, {w -> 
 0.00191167}}, {{w -> 0.0302949}, {w -> 0.00671401}, {w -> 
 0.0026321}, {w -> 0.00131905}}, {{w -> 0.119177}, {w -> 
 0.012046}, {w -> 0.00383985}, {w -> 0.0017433}, {w -> 
 0.000948279}}};

elems = Level[data, {-1}]
elems[[2 ;; ;; 2]]
Select[elems, NumericQ] == %
DeleteCases[elems, w] == %%
```

> {w, 0.25, w, 0.05, w, 0.190065, w, 0.0182686, w, 0.0404842, w, \
>   0.0086731, w, 0.156634, w, 0.015429, w, 0.00478921, w, 0.0344873, w, \
>   0.00753932, w, 0.00292085, w, 0.134788, w, 0.0134812, w, 0.00424987, \
>   w, 0.00191167, w, 0.0302949, w, 0.00671401, w, 0.0026321, w, \
>   0.00131905, w, 0.119177, w, 0.012046, w, 0.00383985, w, 0.0017433, w, \
>   0.000948279}
>
> {0.25, 0.05, 0.190065, 0.0182686, 0.0404842, 0.0086731, 0.156634, \
>   0.015429, 0.00478921, 0.0344873, 0.00753932, 0.00292085, 0.134788, \
>   0.0134812, 0.00424987, 0.00191167, 0.0302949, 0.00671401, 0.0026321, \
>   0.00131905, 0.119177, 0.012046, 0.00383985, 0.0017433, 0.000948279}
>
> True
>
> True